# ES2015 Default parameters not working on chrome

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So I am using *`Chrome Version 47.0.2526.73 (64-bit)`*, and testing my new code on chrome which;

```
function addRowLine(rowNum = 0, isVisible = false)
{
    console.log(rowNum);
}
```

And I got;

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =(…)

But, this code works fine on *`Firefox 42.0`*

So, I just want to clarify if chrome doesn't support this feature yet? Or I am missing something.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) says you need Chrome 49 and sometimes in Chrome you need to be in strict mode too.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome 47 doesn't support this yet. It will be supported in Chrome 49.

You can find a compatibility table here: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: Chrome 49 is not released yet, is it? Btw, thanks for the reference.

Comment: It will be officially released on 15th january. http://www.chromium.org/developers/calendar

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if that's still true. Because 48 should already be released according to the calendar?